# Find slowest to compile dependencies in webpack build?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to use the webpack profile and analyze features to find the node_modules that are adding the most to the compilation time. What is the best way to accomplish this with Webpack 2?

Comment: run `webpack --profile` to see the building times for each modules

Comment: This will hide dependencies inside `node_modules` by default. To show those you have to add the `--display-modules` flag. The problem is though that it will split out all the individual imports within a `node_module`. I want to see the dependency as a whole. See this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5clzp68x8jyhkx/Screenshot%202017-03-28%2009.13.41.png?dl=1